# Singleton and @Autowired returning NULL

Tags: spring, singleton, autowired

I have a repository manager that manages my repositories.  I have the @Autowired to instantiate my properties, but they are always null.  The beans are correctly configured in my xml.  Any reason why?

```
public class RepositoryManager {

        private static RepositoryManager instance;

        private RepositoryManager()
        {
        }

       public static RepositoryManager Instance()
       {
            if(instance == null)
                 instance  = new RepositoryManager();

            return instance;
        }

        @Autowired
        private IUserRepository userRepository;

        @Autowired
        private IRoleRepository roleRepository;

        @Autowired
        private IAssetRepository assetRepository;

        public IUserRepository getUserRepository() {
            return userRepository;
        }

        public void setUserRepository(IUserRepository userRepository) {
            this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public IRoleRepository getRoleReposttory() {
            return roleRepository;
        }

        public void setRoleReposttory(IRoleRepository roleRepository) {
            this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }

        public IAssetRepository getAssetRepository() {
            return assetRepository;
        }

        public void setAssetRepository(IAssetRepository assetRepository) {
            this.assetRepository = assetRepository;
        }
    }
```

dao.xml

```
    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cisco.badges.data.*" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
      </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
          <list>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.User</value>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.Role</value>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.Asset</value>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.UserRole</value>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.UserRole$UserRolePK</value>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.UserAsset</value>
              <value>com.cisco.badges.data.domain.UserAsset$UserAssetPK</value>
          </list>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <tx:annotation-driven/>

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

userrepository.java

```
    @Repository("userRepository")
public class UserRepository extends
        BaseRepository<User, Long> implements
        IUserRepository {

    @Autowired
    public UserRepository(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }
```

Comment: If the beans *were* configured correctly, your fields wouldn't be null. Show us the config.

Comment: I added the xml and sample repository.  The same repository can be injected manually with it being a property in a controller, but within this static method it isn't getting filled.

Comment: (a) Why is `RepositoryManager` managing its own singleton? (b) Where is `RepositoryManager` defined in Spring?  What package is it in? (c) Why are you declaring explicit repository beans when you've already declared a component-scan?

Comment: a.) Fixed that singleton syntax
b.) I added @Component on RepositoryManager, and it is in package com.cisco.badges.data.repositories;
c.) I removed them from the xml, and am just using annotations

Same thing is happening

Answer (score 22):

I just ran into this myself. The problem is that when you do

```
new RepositoryManager();
```

in Instance(), you are not using Spring to create RepositoryManager, and thus the dependency injection isn't happening for your instance (no autowiring).

The solution is to do away with the Instance() singleton pattern. If you want to insist on a Singleton, then do this

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class RepositoryManager {
    ...
}
```

Then wherever you need the repository manager, just autowire in a reference to it (assuming the calling bean is also managed by Spring!)

```
@Autowired
private RepositoryManager repositoryManager = null;
```

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure that you have the following in your config:

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="name.of.your.package"></context:component-scan>
```

If you have it then post your configuration xml

Comment: I have annotation-driven, and the component-scan

Comment: I think you need <context:annotation-config /> as well please look at this example http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/ and I also looking at my code and I see it there.

Comment: Same thing.  I think it has to do with the singleton part of it?

Comment: Maybe, can you you please answer @skaffman questions? anyway this is very interesting question.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a very elegant way to have your cake and eat it, i.e., have a JVM singleton that's also Spring-managed. Say you have a pure java singleton with an autowired bean like this:

```
public final class MySingletonClass{
  private static MySingletonClass instance;

  public static MySingletonClass getInstance(){
    if(instance==null){
      synchronized{
        if(instance==null){
          instance = new MySingletonClass();
        }
      }
    }
    return instance;
  }

  @Autowired
  private SomeSpringBean bean;

  // other singleton methods omitted
}
```

You can force Spring to manage this singleton simply by adding in your application context the following line:

```
<bean class="com.mypackage.MySingletonClass" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

Now your singleton will have an instance of `SomeSpringBean` autowired (if available in the context).

Moreover, this is a 'fix' for the typical problem with Spring singleton beans that are not truly JVM singletons because they get instantiated by Spring. Using the pattern above enforces JVM level singleton, i.e., compiler enforced singleton, together with container singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of the static method `Instance()`

you are creating the POJO outside of the spring context.

you can fix this, by adding `<context:spring-configured />` to your configuration, and then annotating `RepositoryManager` with `@Configurable`