# Generate static map from database using a singleton class also using spring configuration @Autowired

Tags: spring, singleton, dao, autowired

I need to create an unmodifiable map generated from data obtained by querying a database. How, or can I, or is there a better way to do this using spring annotations?

I ran into a problem when creating a singleton for my **Regions** class and then trying to *@Autowire* in a **RegionService** to grab the object from the DAO. The problem is that spring can't instantiate the RegionService because it needs to instantiate the static singleton class Regions which needs to get data from the database as shown below in the constructor.

Please see me classes below (I've removed multiple unneeded methods that don't pertain to this question):

```
public final class Region {
private static final String DEFAULT_SEPERATOR = "-";
private final Integer key;
private final String description;

public Region(Integer pKey, String pDescription) {
    this.key = pKey;
    this.description = pDescription;
}

public Integer getKey() {
    return this.key;
}

public String getValue() {
    return this.description;
}
}
```

Here is my singleton:

```
public final class Regions {
private static Regions regionsInstance = null;

@Autowired
private RegionService regionService;

static Map<Integer, Region> regions;

private Regions() {
    final Map<Integer, Region> tempRegions = new HashMap<Integer, Region>();
    for (final Region region : this.regionService.retrieveAll()) {
        tempRegions.put(region.getKey(), region);
    }
    regions = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempRegions);
}

public static synchronized Regions getRegionsInstance() {
    if (regionsInstance == null) {
        regionsInstance = new Regions();
    }
    return regionsInstance;
}

public Region getRegion(final Integer pKey) {
    return regions.get(pKey);
}

public List<Region> getRegions() {
    return (List<Region>) regions.values();
}
}
```

My DAO and Service are just interfaces, no need to post those, here are my Impls:

```
@Service
public class RegionServiceImpl implements RegionService {

@Autowired
private RegionDAO regionDao;

@Override
public List<Region> retrieveAll() {
    return this.regionDao.retrieveAll();
}
}
```

My DAOImpl (tested and works, just posting to give you the full picture):

```
@Repository
public class RegionDAOImpl implements RegionDAO {
private static final String SQL_RETRIEVE_REGIONS = "some random SQL";
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public List<Region> retrieveAll() {
    try {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_RETRIEVE_REGIONS, new ResultSetExtractor<List<Region>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Region> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                return RegionDAOImpl.this.mapRegionData(rs);
            }
        });
    } catch (final DataAccessException dae) {
        throw new DaoException("Could not retrieve regionList from database. " + dae);
    }
}

protected final List<Region> mapRegionData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    final List<Region> regionList = new ArrayList<Region>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        regionList.add(new Region(rs.getInt("REGION_CD"), rs.getString("REGION_TXT")));
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(regionList);
}
```

}

Then I run my test(I took out unneeded crap):

```
@..annotated with things you don't need to know
public class RetrieveRegionsTest {
@Autowired
private Regions r;

@Test
public void getAndLogRegion() {

final List<Region> regionDescriptions = new ArrayList<Region>(this.r.getRegions());
    for (final Region region : regionDescriptions) {
        LOGGER.info(region.getValue());
    }
}
```

Yes my configuration and classpaths are set up properly. I can get this to work other ways, just not by accessing the **Regions** singleton which is what I want. Now I know I could take off the *@Autowired* on the **RegionService** in my Regions singleton and just create a new instance of RegionService, but that would defeat the purpose of springs @Autowired feature.

Any thoughts, ideas, comments?

Comment: I did find this post, bu it did not solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010219/singleton-and-autowired-returning-null. Look for the first comment.

Comment: You should not mix Java singleons and Spring singleton beans. Ever. The latter can depend on the former(obviously they don't need Spring to access Java singletons) but a static object depending on a nonstatic object to fulfill its contract makes no sense. You should either refactor your static singleton into non static singleton bean or change the contract so that the non static classes will be the source  of action.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes I should probably refactor. I assume from your comment you know what I am trying to do; populate a static class with values from the database. This is so no one can modify those values and also, there would only be one instance of the class.

Do you have any recommendations on how to create something like this? Links to examples are helpful :)

Comment: I would give up idea of static class and move the respective logic to RegionService and then access it from Spring application context - Spring beans are singletons by default, and usually there's only one/two Spring contexts so your service is singleton bean(by default all spring beans are singletons). You can pass the reference to RegionService interface to the logic that previously used static class(but you should probably make it also DI compatible).