# Spring's application context available everywhere - Set application context in a static variable

Tags: java, spring

Instead of "struggling" to inject or pass common Spring beans everywhere it is needed, especially in non Spring managed class, is it a good practice to set the Spring's application context in a static variable to get it from anywhere ? Doing that allow for example to get the JdbcTemplate singleton in a non Spring managed class (or the Hibernate session factory). Is there good reason to not doing that ?

for example :

```
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return applicationContext.getBean(SessionFactory.class);
    }

    public static Session getCurrentSession() {
        SessionFactory sf = applicationContext.getBean(SessionFactory.class);
        return sf.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

In another class, not managed by Spring :

```
public class MyClass {

    public Integer method1() {
        String sql = "select 1 from dual";
        Integer n = SpringContext.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
        return n;
    }

}
```

Comment: The Spring philosophy is to have everything container managed, so your scenario will never happen. However, you need to bend the rules sometimes. I recommend creating actual singletons when you need them and have spring inject their dependencies. Look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010219/singleton-and-autowired-returning-null).

Answer (score 1):

This seems counter to Spring's intended usage, and to the concept of *dependency injection*. Whilst you could do this, I think the *better* solution is to inject those beans where required.

I find it a good practice to initialise the context *once*, reference a 'root' bean, and that bean would essentially be the application and contain references (directly or indirectly) to every other bean in the system.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I know that Dependency Injection is a proven pattern. But I am not sure I want to be "prisoner" of that. I understand the philosophy behind IoC and loosely coupled components, but in practice, honnestly, some exceptions are acceptable. Especially if it makes your life easier as a developer. Sometimes I need to put a bit of intelligence in real POJO not managed by Spring and not stick with silly value holder. Accessing Spring bean this way is very convenient. I was just wondering if, from a pure runtime point of view, it won't lead to bad situations.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a singleton, i.e., a class of which there exists only one instance, that is also a Spring managed singleton (a singleton scoped bean). I found a very elegant solution to this problem when I was using Spring a few years ago. Let's say your singleton looks like this:

```
public final class MySingletonClass{
  private static MySingletonClass instance = new MySingletonClass();

  public static MySingletonClass getInstance(){
    return instance;
  }

  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  // getters and other methods omitted
}
```

You can force Spring to manage this singleton simply by adding in your application context the following line:

```
<bean class="com.mypackage.MySingletonClass" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

Now your singleton will have all the above Spring-managed objects autowired (if available in the context) and can be used by any non-Spring managed class:

```
class MyClass {
  // Can only be called after Spring initialized.
  void doSomething() {
    DataSource ds = MySingletonClass.getInstance().getDataSource();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Every object that you believe needs to be an actual singleton can use the above pattern. This preserves the Spring approach to object life cycle management and dependency injection providing the safety of a true singleton object. Moreover, the singleton will be Spring managed so all its dependencies will be properly wired or the application will fail at application startup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Giovanni. However, I don't really see the value of your proposition. In my example, SpringContext is already a singleton as it is a Spring bean (annotated with @Component) and the default scope of Spring to create beans is singleton. I can do SprintContext.getMyBean() (static method) instead of MySingletonClass.getInstance().getMyBean() in your example. Maybe, I miss something.

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't expose the context. You should design your application's singletons as pure Java singletons. Except your singletons will be managed by spring behind the curtains. The advantage of this is that your application is not tied to the Spring context so if you end up changing DI engine later you can do it transparently. The other advantage is that even though you have a pure Java singleton, i.e., only one static instance exists, the instance is still managed by Spring so you can use all the magic of injection.

Comment: Compared to your example there are small differences, most notably automatic injection instead of manual getters, which also means if any bean is misconfigured it will be caught by Spring right away instead of when your static method gets called, which could be at any point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web application, you can use the class `org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils` from Spring. It provides a method to get the root WebApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want beans that are not "managed by Spring" but have access to Spring beans.
[Prototype scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.7/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) exists for that purpose: you let Spring instantiate the class and inject any necessary dependencies, and then you control that bean's lifecycle yourself (Spring doesn't care about it anymore).